# Entity Framework обновить только одну сущность(таблицу)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sql-server

Есть у меня есть некая модель из Entity Framework. Необходимо как-то обновить только 1 сущность (то есть 1 таблицу заполнить данными из базы).

*Например*: изменили что-то в базе вне программы и только в одной таблице, как мне обновить только 1 таблицу. Я же делаю пока просто пересозданием всего контента:

```
_dataContext = new MyMagnEntities();
```

Потому как другого способа пока не нашел. Как сделать правильно?

Comment: а данные, как я понимаю, в datagridview выводятся?

Comment: Мне кажется, так думать неправильно. EF (как и все остальные OR/M) для того и придумана, чтобы абстрагироваться от самого наличия таблиц.

В любом случае, ваша стратегия неверна: контексты EF [должны быть короткоживущими](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd882522.aspx). Вы не должны кешировать их и искать момент, когда нужно пересоздать. Просто пересоздавайте каждый раз.

Answer (score 2):

Контекст - это не "копия базы в памяти". Нет смысла его "обновлять". Контекст - это именно объект для хранения контекста одной операции (операции в терминах бизнес-логики, а не в смысле операции вставки/удаления).

Сам по себе класс контекста - это не только и не столько реализация паттерна Repository, сколько реализация паттерноа [Unit Of Work](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/unitOfWork.html). А суть Unit Of Work:

> Maintains a list of objects affected by **a business transaction** and coordinates the writing out of changes and the resolution of concurrency problems.

Само название класса это отражает - это "контекст [операции]". Он хранит промежуточную информацию об изменениях в рамках текущей операции. В том числе и информацию об уже загруженных в рамках операции объектах.

Из этого напряму следуюет то, что контексты должны быть короткоживущими. Их нужно создавать в начале бизнес-операции и сразу же выбрасывать в конце. Попытка сделать "один контекст на приложение" заведомо обречена на подпирание костылями.

Хаки вида

```
context.Entry(entity).Reload()
```

предназначены не для ежедневного применения. А, скорее, для случаев когда в рамках одной операции *действительно* ожидается изменение объекта извне.

Answer (score 0):

У меня была подобная проблема, первоначально решил ее с помощью пересоздания контекста. Ссылаюсь на [источник1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20270599/entity-framework-refresh-context), [источник2](https://christianarg.wordpress.com/2013/06/13/entityframework-refreshall-loaded-entities-from-database/) и небольшой свой опыт по решению данной проблемы, это самый быстрый и правильный способ.